# Reading a line from a text file and splitting its contents

Tags: java, file, file-structure

I have this kind of file structure

> ```
> MALE:FooBar:32
> FEMALE:BarFoo:23
> ```

Where I would want to identify the gender and age of person, `<Gender>:<Name>:<age>`

```
try{
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("people.ser"));
    String s;

    while((s = in.readLine()) != null){

        String[] var = s.split(":");
             //var[0]=MALE etc etc
        addGender.add(var[0]);
    }

}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

- Is using a delimiter (like a `:` in this case) to split string considered a bad practice?
- What about using the array from the splitted string to store it in some place?
- Are there any alternatives and better file structure?

Comment: String.split(RegEx) is the now recommended  for new Java'versions (StringTokenizer for old version compatibility). With 'palacsint' advices, you code look fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think that using `:` is a bad practice but you have to escape it somehow if it occurs inside your data. Anyway, I'd consider using XML or JSON here.

Some notes about the code:

1. You should close the stream (in a `finally` block). See *Guideline 1-2: Release resources in all cases* in [Secure Coding Guidelines for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/seccodeguide-139067.html)
2. The `.ser` file extension is often used for serialized Java objects. I'd use something else to avoid the possible confusion.
3. It's a good practice to set the character set when you read a text file. The used `FileReader` always uses the default charset which could vary from system to system. Consider using `InputStreamReader` and `FileInputStream` as the [documentation of `FileReader` says](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html). Here is an example:

   ```
   FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
   InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = null;
   BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
   try {
       fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("people.dat");
       inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream, "UTF-8");
       bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

       // use BufferedReader here
   } finally {
       IOUtils.closeQuietly(bufferedReader);
       IOUtils.closeQuietly(inputStreamReader);
       IOUtils.closeQuietly(fileInputStream);
   }
   ```

   It uses [`IOUtils` from Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) and closes the `FileInputStream` even if the constructor of `InputStreamReader` or `BufferedReader` throws an exception.

Comment: How would I do number 3?

Comment: @KyelJmD: See the edit, please.

Comment: why did you use final?

Comment: @KyelJmD: `final` helps readers and maintainers, because they know that the reference always points to the same instance and it doesn't change later. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/115690/why-declare-final-variables-inside-methods but you can find other questions on Programmers.SE in the topic.

Comment: I would place those final variables in the class? or inside a method that calls them?

Comment: @KyelJmD: I've added a more detailed example.

Answer (score 4):

Scanner is a bit easier to use then BufferedReader...

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        try {
            File f = new File("people.ser");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);

            List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();

            while(sc.hasNextLine()){
                String line = sc.nextLine();
                String[] details = line.split(":");
                String gender = details[0];
                String name = details[1];
                int age = Integer.parseInt(details[2]);
                Person p = new Person(gender, name, age);
                people.add(p);
            }

            for(Person p: people){
                System.out.println(p.toString());
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {         
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class Person{

    private String gender;
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Person(String gender, String name, int age){
        this.gender = gender;
        this.setName(name);
        this.age = age;
    }

    /**
     * @return the gender
     */
public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}

/**
 * @param gender the gender to set
 */
public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}

/**
 * @param name the name to set
 */
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

/**
 * @return the name
 */
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

/**
 * @return the age
 */
public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

/**
 * @param age the age to set
 */
public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public String toString(){
    return this.gender + " " + this.name + " " + this.age;
}


}
```

Comment: `toString()` method should use `StringBuilder` instead of concatenation.

Comment: Since the toString() method is likely only used for debugging purposes, I'd say readability trumps performance here and the current implementation is a lot more readable. In case it is used in heavy iteration, that might be a different case.